# Worklight Application Center v5.0.5 - Apps fail at download stage for ios6, works for ios5

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to download applications from my Worklight Application Center Client (5.0.5 version) on an iPhone 5 runnning ios 6.1.2.

9 times out of 10 the download and install of the application will fail, whilst 1 in 10 times it will download and install correctly.

I have also tried using an iPhone running io5.1 and the install works fine. It also works fine on an iPad running ios5.1. It fails on another iPhone running ios6.0

I have checked issues such as signing of the apps and if I am using a correct UDID and I can say that these are not causing the issue, especially when you consider that it works some of them time.

It seems to be something to do with ios6 specifically.
Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior or can offer any help in terms of resolving it?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation with iOS 6 seems better with Worklight 5.0.6, to be released in the near future.

Comment: Ok thanks, Will look into it when I get a chance to upgrade. 
Does 5.0.6 solve the IP issues with the app store? I did not see it in the update documentation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with an IP issue so I do not know.